# Как правильно писать врача

Tags: приложение, дефис

Как правильно подписать врача (интересует расстановка дефиса именно в этих случаях):
1. врач-флеболог, сосудистый хирург;
2. врач-рентгенолог, маммолог.

Нужен ли в обоих случаях вместо запятой дефис?

Comment: Не понял: в первом случае это синоним, а во втором? Два разных врача? В чём смысл?

Comment: Человек имеет в виду следующее: „Как правильно написать главное слово и приложения при нём при условии, что обе конструкции являются нарицательными и не относятся к общим исключениям”. Например, у нас есть **инженер-строитель**. А теперь представим, что он ещё и проектировщик. Суть заключается в том, как в одном слове (в действительности мы понимаем, что приложение является всё тем же определением, но зачастую употребляющиеся с дефисом) уместить смысл всех трёх понятий: „инженер”, „строитель” и „проектировщик”.

Comment: Правильный ответ надо искать в перечне специальностей медвузов и клиник. Вопрос-то специфический.

Comment: @sampar С тем, что вопрос специфический, полностью согласен.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что отраслевая терминология не обсуждается.

Comment: @shampar согласно [справке](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) не вижу, почему этот вопрос не по теме.

Comment: «Все рекомендации будут до известной степени субъективны», как сказано в хорошем ответе на хороший вопрос. Вам же нужен объективный (см. мой комментарий).

Answer (score 1):

Хороший вопрос...
Случай, насколько могу судить, в правилах явно не прописан, особенно первый пример. Так что все рекомендации будут до известной степени субъективны.

Есть негласное правило, что двух дефисов в одном слове не бывает. Это, конечно, не совсем так, но вот в нашем случае оно вполне действенно. Когда одному поясняемому понятию соответствует сразу два приложения, два дефиса вносят большую путаницу. Так что два дефиса здесь не выход. Но и запятая при перечислении приложений не выход.

Могу лишь предложить заменить дефис на тире, а запятую тогда в втором случае вполне можно заменить дефисом.

Вряд ли такую рекомендацию вы где-то найдете, но аналоги есть. "Инженер — генерал-майор", к примеру.

Так что я за
***Врач — рентгенолог-маммолог***

В первом случае заменять на дефис нельзя, ибо там не два простых слова связывают. Вот там бы тире пригодилось, но оно уже "занято".
Остается только так.

***Врач — флеболог, сосудистый хирург.***

Из "литературы" могу дать только ссылку на обсуждение на "грамотном" форуме.
http://newforum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=6363&sid=bfda1394201a6d9377695ab16861ae38

Answer (score -1):

Что касается первого сочетания, я уверенно могу сказать, что постановка дефиса здесь невозможна из-за распространённости одного из „приложений” (в действительности это можно назвать СИС в неполном предложении. Подобный вопрос неоднократно обсуждался на форуме, поэтому, если Вам интересно, можете обратиться ко мне за соответствующими ссылками), что уже было изложено участниками форума при решении очередной задачи (здесь ссылку уже дать не могу, поскольку в то время не имел никакого отношения к вопросу). Если я правильно помню, Вам следует обратиться к поисковику с темой „правописание сложных существительных”. А вот насчёт второго примера однозначный ответ дать не могу, но осмелюсь предположить, что всё сочетание должно писаться через дефис: врач-рентгенолог-маммолог. Это уже исключительно моё мнение, поэтому лучше послушайте более осведомлённых участников форума.